What is the canonical way to run pytest with Python 3.11 in Amazon Linux 2023 containers?
AWS provides support for installing python 3.11 in Amazon Linux 2023 containers.
However it isn't at all obvious how you install and run a compatible pytest in this case.
For example, if you do this:
dnf install -y pytest
the version of pytest installed is the 3.9 version which is compatible with the so-called system version of Python which is 3.9 but is not compatible with python3.11 installed via the supported method.
So what is the canonical way for installing a version of pytest which is compatible with the python3.11 as installed in the manner recommended by AWS?

The best way is probably to set up a 3.11 virtual environment and install pytest into that environment:
bash-5.2# python3.11 -m venv .venv
bash-5.2# . .venv/bin/activate
(.venv) bash-5.2# pip install pytest
Collecting pytest
.
.
.
(.venv) bash-5.2#

Now running pytest gets you pytest for Python 3.11. You will of course want to install any other dependencies into the virtual environment; a common setup is to put runtime dependencies in requirements.txt and test requirements (like pytest) into test-requirements.txt, so that you setup process looks like:
bash-5.2# python3.11 -m venv .venv
bash-5.2# . .venv/bin/activate
(.venv) bash-5.2# pip install -r requirements.txt
(.venv) bash-5.2# pip install -r test-requirements.txt
(.venv) bash-5.2# pytest
.
.
.


Alternately, you can install a version of pip to go along with your python3.11 install:
bash-5.2# dnf install python3.11-pip

And then globally install pytest using pip:
bash-5.2# pip3.11 install pytest
Collecting pytest
  Using cached pytest-8.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (342 kB)
Collecting iniconfig
  Using cached iniconfig-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.9 kB)
Collecting packaging
  Using cached packaging-24.2-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
Collecting pluggy<2,>=1.5
  Using cached pluggy-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Installing collected packages: pluggy, packaging, iniconfig, pytest
Successfully installed iniconfig-2.0.0 packaging-24.2 pluggy-1.5.0 pytest-8.3.3
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

But as the warning says, installing things globally like this can lead to conflicts.
